# Persistent BottomSheet Views do not get focus in Talkback mode on (Accessibility)

Tags: android, accessibility

i have a persistent bottomsheet like  `bottom_sheet_persistent.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Text in Bottom Sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the activity where the bottomsheet has been used is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#E7E7E7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    
                <TextView
                    android:text="Text in Activity"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
                layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_persistent" />
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I turn on the talkback of accessibility and the bottom sheet is expanded, the text in Activity (will be overlapped by the botttomsheet's textview) which is underneath the bottomsheet gets the focus. How can I get the focus which in on the bottomsheet (seems to be so obvious). I tried to make the bottomsheet clickable, but in that case, the whole bottomsheet gets the focus not the individual items.

Any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom sheet layout's parent view will be like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

Comment: did it resolve the issue. I am having the same issue. When Persistent BottomSheet  opens, Accessibility talk still read the content from bottom. What is the root cause and how did you fix that.? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @sadat, I tried to make exact parent layout as you suggested but talk back does not focus on the persistent bottom sheet when it opens. Could you please help to share your experience. How did it work in your case. Thanks.

Comment: @VP4Android did you manage to block the talk back to read the content behind the bottomsheet.

Comment: @VP4Android the above solution actually works for me. The main issue was the underneath view was getting the focus, but if the make the bottomsheet clickable as suggested, it actually does not pass the focus to the underneath views. tested in Pixel 3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it call performAccessibilityAction() explicitly.
Try this on the bottom sheet.

```
yourView.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS,null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [BottomSheetBehaviour.setUpdateImportantForAccessibilityOnSiblings(Boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setUpdateImportantForAccessibilityOnSiblings(boolean)) is what you are looking for.

When you set it to `true`, it basically tells the accessibility service to ignore all views under your BottomSheet while it's expanded, allowing TalkBack to focus only views contained in your bottom sheet.